# How do I switch the end function?

Tags: java

As in, the value as the end where it says "X dollars converts to Y russian ruble" (after the two Digits new Decimal Format) - the problem is that it can be russian ruble, british pound, or euro. How can I differentiate? (text inserted at line in question)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class CurrencyConversion extends Applet implements ItemListener
{
 //declare variables and color
 double dollars, answer;
 int empCode;
 Image dollarSign;
 Color darkRed = new Color(160, 50, 0);

 //Create components for applet
 Label promptLabel = new Label("Enter the dollar amount (do not use commas or dollar signs):");
  TextField currencyField = new TextField(20);

 Label codeLabel = new Label ("Select the desired currency:");

 CheckboxGroup codeGroup = new CheckboxGroup () ;
  Checkbox britishpoundBox = new Checkbox("British Pound",false,codeGroup);
  Checkbox euroBox = new Checkbox("Euro",false,codeGroup);
  Checkbox russianrubleBox = new Checkbox("Russian Ruble",false,codeGroup);
  Checkbox hiddenBox = new Checkbox("",true,codeGroup);


 Label outputLabel = new Label("Click an option to convert the desired currency.");

 public void init()
 {
  setBackground(darkRed);
  setForeground(Color.white);
  add(promptLabel);
  add(currencyField);
  currencyField.requestFocus();
  currencyField.setForeground(Color.black);
  add(codeLabel);
  add(britishpoundBox);
  britishpoundBox.addItemListener(this);
  add(euroBox);
  euroBox.addItemListener(this);
  add(russianrubleBox);
  russianrubleBox.addItemListener(this);
  add(outputLabel);
 }

 //This method is triggered by click
 public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent choice)
 {
  try
  {
   dollars = getCurrency();
   empCode = getCode();
   answer = getComm(dollars,empCode);
   output(answer, dollars);
  }

  catch (NumberFormatException e)
  {
   outputLabel.setText("You must enter a dollar amount greater than zero.");
   hiddenBox.setState(true);
   currencyField.setText("");
   currencyField.requestFocus();
  }
 }

 public double getCurrency()
 {
  double currency = Double.parseDouble(currencyField.getText());

  if (currency <= 0) throw new NumberFormatException();

  return currency;
 }

 public int getCode()
 {
  int code = 0;
  if (britishpoundBox.getState()) code = 1;
  else
   if (euroBox.getState()) code = 2;
   else
    if (russianrubleBox.getState()) code = 3;
  return code;
 }

 public double getComm(double currency, int code)
 {
  double amount = 0.0;
  switch(code)
  {
   case 1:
    amount = .79610 * currency;
    break;
   case 2:
    amount = .70880 * currency;
    break;
   case 3:
    amount = 35.88240 * currency;
    break;
  }
  return amount;
 }

 public void output(double amount, double currency)
 {
  DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
  outputLabel.setText("Your amount of " + twoDigits.format(currency) + " dollars converts to " + twoDigits.format(amount) RIGHT HERE - what do I do? );
 }

 public void paint(Graphics g)
 {
  dollarSign = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "dollarsign.gif");
  g.drawImage(dollarSign,12,28,this);
 }
}
```

Comment: If you hardcode the exchange rates in the program, you need to update it very frequently. At the very least put them in a properties files that can be updated externally.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mapping from `Integer` to `String`, populate it with the various currency descriptions, and pass the `Integer` to the output function so that you can get the description from the mapping.

Comment: Like `Map<Integer, String> currencyMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>(); currencyMap.put(1, "Russian rubles"); ...` or however that would look in valid Java code.

Comment: I hope you're not *paying* for the class. AWT is dead.

Comment: No, I'm not. Is there any simple solution. If there is not, then that is fine. I get 16 errors with your method lol.

Comment: The simple solution is to pass the currency string to the function.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea how to do that (it is an introductory course btw). It's okay, you don't have to finish it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the currency concept into its own object. Override the ToString() method and return the name of the currency or define an explicit property to return the currency type. Pass the currency object around instead of the not so complex double and make the rate which was previously the double a property on the object.

Comment: If we are going that way, an enum might be an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use class java.util.Currency. The exchange rate of each currency should not be hard coded. For first phase just put it into properties file, i.e.:
RUB=35.88240
GBP=.79610

Avoid using hard coded list of currencies. Instead parse this property file, extract all keys, then use Currency.getInstance(currencyCode). Both UI and logic will be generic. Your application will be at least twice shorter and much more flexible.